# DLL method call returns different results when called from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, dll, service, windows-services

I have a program I'm converting to a Windows Service (in C#). This program interacts with an external DLL that has a method that returns an object. The object shows the state of another running program (whether it is running, and whether the program is logged in)

With the previous implementation, everything worked fine. The DLL call to get the object with the state variables in it worked fine. Now that I have moved that method call to the Windows Service, it returns the wrong values. The DLL method call returns the state object, but the values always show that the program is not running or logged in (when it clearly is).

I have no idea why calling this DLL method inside a Windows Service should change the variables returned.

Is there something I can do to make sure the DLL call works as intended?

I have no access to the DLL code, so the change cannot be made there.

Here's an example:

```
AppStateDLL.AppStateObject stateObject = new AppStateDLL.AppStateObject();
if (!stateObject.Online || !stateObject.LoggedIn)
{
    //things are broken, because the program is always running and logged in
}
```

(the names are made up, but you get the idea)
If I run this code in a Windows Forms object, the stateObject has the Online and LoggedIn properties set as true, so everythings good. If I run the code from within the Windows Service, I get false returned for both variables.

And my Windows Service is set with LocalSystem access, which I believe should mean it should have no issues with permissions and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that the service is running in a different session and thus a different desktop from the app whose status it is trying to report on.

This DLL probably calls EnumWindow to find the app and this would fail to locate it when run from a different desktop.

Comment: Good guessing... Maybe running the service allowing it to interact with the desktop changes something?

Comment: @haplo that setting no longer has any effect

Comment: Not for W2K8 or Vista/W7. But in XP, which still many people use, still applies, isn't it?

Comment: It's been quite a long time since I was implementing services that needed to interact with the desktop... but I just found this, maybe it's useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx, In windows 7, it seems that you need to start an additional service, the Interactive Service detection.

Comment: @haplo that's right but session 0 isolation has been with us for so long now I tend to regard that as the baseline. If something can only be done in XP then it's not really worth consideration in my view.

Comment: @haplo Read the article more closely. I don't understand why people have such a hard time accepting that services can't interact with the desktop. The news broke 5 years ago and still there is disbelief. If you need access to a user desktop then run an app on that desktop and communicate with the service using IPC.

Comment: @David hefferman - I think is easy to understand... many people don't implement new projects everyday. If you do so, then adhere to the rules, which I've done in a project not long ago running on W2k8. But if you are working maintaining or extending legacy software, many chances are that your boss doesn't want to hear about making further changes to a system... lucky you if you have such freedom !! :)

Comment: @haplo I see what you mean but I've seen so many debates on SO where people refuse to believe that services can't interact with desktop. You yourself suggested that it could be done just by running another service!

Comment: @David hefferman - I had to implement an application that substituted a lot of manual work by automating UI interaction. Multiple people send instructions to our 'robot', running in a server. There we open a browser and start performing what previously was done manually. The easiest way was to implement a service that exposes WCF to receive and queue UI work items, and then performs the automation. No one logs into the OS. But this is a specific problem, and in general, if users are going to log into a machine, I completely agree that services shoudn't interact with the desktop.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Any way I could possibly get around this?

Comment: call the dll from a standard app running on a logged in user's desktop

Comment: Is there any way to hook into the currently active desktop so I can run it from there? As in, the service checks if the user is logged in, and if so, runs the DLL from the current users desktop context? Or is that a silly question?

Comment: no you can't do that. Dlls are hosted by processes. The don't have their own context, they have that of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since we don't know anything about the internals of your `AppStateObject`, I can only make a rough guess. You told us

> The object shows the state of another running program

Perhaps it shows only the state of the other program correctly if both programs run within the same user context? Which might be not the case when you make your program run as a service?